# Как правильно писать Null-коалесцентный оператор?

Tags: php

Есть функция :

```
   public function full_name()
{
    if (!empty($this->first_name) && !empty($this->last_name)) {
        return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Вчера вечером читая форум , советуют использовать уже синтаксис новый, но я не могу понять что я делаю не так :

```
public function full_login()
{
   return $log = $this->first_name ?? $this->last_name ?? "";
}
```

Возвращает только $this->first_name. Где моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите мануал [PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php)

Вот пример из мануала:

```
Начиная с PHP 7, добавился новый оператор "??" (или null coalescing).

Пример Вложенный оператор null coalescing

<?php

$foo = null;
$bar = null;
$baz = 1;
$qux = 2;

echo $foo ?? $bar ?? $baz ?? $qux; // выведет 1

?>
```

Все выводит верно. Оно выводит первый элемент который не `NULL`.

Comment: Спасибо . Думал он выводит все переменные которые не null. Не внимательно прочел офф док. ТТ.

Comment: Поставил, спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете совсем разные модели сравнения и получения результата. В первом случае у вас составной результат, а в последнем ЛИБО, ЛИБО, ЛИБО. Это совсем разные вещи.

```
public function full_name()
{
    return trim($this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name);
}
```

Так, на мой взгляд, вернее будет. Точнее, сохраняется смысл вашего кода.